# How to do linq joins with multiple conditions + ORs

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to know how to do a linq join with multiple conditions and ORs.

Example:

```
var i = (from d in context.Table1
         join b in context.Table2
         on new {r1 = d.col1, r2 = d.col2}
         equals new {r1 = b.col1, r2 = b.col2}
         || b.col3.ToLower() equals "xyz"
         into bd
         from k in bd.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

The ORs part is blowing up.

SQL example:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON (T1.Col1 = T2.Col1 AND T1.Col2 =T2.Col2) 
                     OR (T1.Col1 = T2.Col1 AND T2.Col2 = 'XYZ')
```

Explanation:

T1.Col1 must match T2.COl1 - REQUIRED JOIN

Then

T1.Col2 has to match T2.Col2 unless T2.COl2 = "XYZ" then join only on Col1

Comment: Can you add some textual explanation on what you're trying to achieve? All records from Table1 and the records from Table2 that match the columns of Table1 and... What's the OR supposed to add? Do you perhaps have a working SQL-statement to illustrate your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the "join" into the "Where" clause ala ANSI 82:

```
var i = (from d in context.Table1
         from b in context.Table2
         where (b == null)
               || (d.col1 = b.col1 && d.col2 == b.col2 ) 
               || (b.col3.ToLower() == "xyz")
```

Comment: A where clause will end up filtering it out.. I still want a join and have it return nulls